# How to parse timestamp to day,month and year and time

Tags: java, android, timestamp

I am trying to parse a timestamp into this format **Sat 03 October 2015 15:02**

But i am getting **17 Jan 1970**

My current timestamp is **"1443884578"**

This is the method I use:

```
CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
        Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()), System.currentTimeMillis(),
        DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);

timestamp.setText(timeAgo);
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: *My current timestamp is "1443884578"* it looks like you are using seconds instead of milliseconds. Try with `1443884578000`.

Comment: @Pshemo look at this http://www.timestampgenerator.com/date-from-timestamp/1420293720000/

Comment: Or what timestamp generator are you using?

Comment: My bad, I used `YYYY` instead of `yyyy` (long time since I used `DateFormatter`). Also I have different locale (time zone) so my hour was also a little bit off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other remarked you mixed second and millisenconds. Moreover you don't need to use the getRelativeTimeSpanString to format the string

The code you need is:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(m.getTime())*1000L);
    String date = DateFormat.format("E d MMMM yyyy kk:mm", cal).toString();
```

Comment: I tried  `cal.setTimeInMillis(m.getTime() * 1000L);` but getting `operator '*' cannot be applied to java.lang.String.`

Comment: m.getTime() is my string value

Comment: Ok, if mGetTime you have to parse it (as you did in your question).
I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this URL; http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
 String[] formats = new String[] {
   "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
 };
 for (String format : formats) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
   System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
   System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
 }
```

format() method returns String value, then you can use it for showing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Gregorian Calendar and its methods....
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

And also check out the inherited class Calender!

There are the Fields you can get for each of your desired informations